# empty buffer but IdTCPClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty is false

Tags: delphi, telnet, tcpclient, indy

I have problem in below code with idTCPClient for reading buffer from a telnet server:

```
procedure TForm2.ReadTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
   S: String; 
begin
   if IdTCPClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
   begin
     IdTCPClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(10);
     if IdTCPClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
   end;
   s := idTCPClient.IOHandler.InputBufferAsString(TEncoding.UTF8);
   CheckText(S);
end;
```

this procedure run every 1000 milliseconds and when the buffer have a value CheckText called.

this code works but sometimes this return the empty buffer to CheckText.

what's the problem?

thanks

Comment: I can solve this by removing Encoding type in InputbufferAsString. But the text that receive contain the UTF8 text, and in display of my program I have "YX'Y Z)X'X1X(X1[ X.YX/ X1X' YX'X1X/ Z)Y[X/: 
Z)YYY X9X(YX1:" text :-( , please help me

Comment: One question, why are you not using TidTelnet? This is clearly caused by telnet control characters...

Comment: because idTelnet not support UTF8 and also I want to do some processes on buffer text, and maybe change it before display.

Comment: That is not a valid reason for not using `TIdTelnet`.  It does not care about text encodings. Its `OnDataAvailable` event passes raw bytes to you using a `TIdBytes`.  If you want that in a `String`, you have to copy/decode it yourself after receiving it from `TIdTelnet`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is attempting to read arbitrary blocks of data from the `InputBuffer` and expects them to be complete and valid strings.  It is doing this without **ANY** consideration for what kind of data you are receiving.  That is a recipe for disaster on multiple levels.

You are connected to a Telnet server, but you are using `TIdTCPClient` directly instead of using `TIdTelnet`, so you **MUST** manually decode any Telnet sequences that are received **BEFORE** you can then process any remaining string data.  Look at the source code for `TIdTelnet`. There is a lot of decoding logic that takes place before the `OnDataAvailable` event is fired.  All Telnet sequence data is handled internally, then the `OnDataAvailable` event provides whatever non-Telnet data is left over after decoding.

Once you have Telnet decoding taken care of, another problem you have to watch out for is that `TEncoding.UTF8` only handles properly encoded **COMPLETE** UTF-8 sequences.  If it encounters a badly encoded sequence, or more importantly encounters an incomplete sequence, **THE ENTIRE DECODE FAILS** and it returns a blank string.  This has already been reported as a bug (see [QC #79042](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=79042)).

`CheckForDataOnSource()` stores whatever raw bytes are in the socket **at that moment** into the `InputBuffer`.  `InputBufferAsString()` extracts whatever raw bytes are in the `InputBuffer` **at that moment** and attempts to decode them using the specified encoding.  It is very possible and likely that the raw bytes that are in the `InputBuffer` when you call `InputBufferAsString()` do not always contain **COMPLETE** UTF-8 sequences.  Chances are that sometimes the last sequence in the `InputBuffer` is still waiting for bytes to arrive in the socket and they will not be read until the next call to `CheckForDataOnSource()`. That would explain why your `CheckText()` function is receiving blank strings when using `TEncoding.UTF8`.

You should use `IndyUTF8Encoding()` instead (Indy implements its own UTF-8 encoder/decoder to avoid the decoding bug in `TEncoding.UTF8`).  At the very least, you will not get blank strings anymore, however you can still lose data when a UTF-8 sequence spans multiple `CheckForDataOnSource()` calls (incomplete UTF-8 sequences will be converted to `?` characters).  For that reason alone, you should not be using `InputBufferAsString()` in this situation (even if `TEncoding.UTF8` did work properly). To handle this properly, you should either:

1) scan through the `InputBuffer` manually, calculating how many bytes constitute **COMPLETE** UTF-8 sequences only, and then pass that count to `InputBuffer.Extract()` or `TIdIOHandler.ReadString()`.  Any left over bytes will remain in the `InputBuffer` for the next time.  For that to work, you will have to get rid of the first `InputBufferIsEmpty()` call and just call `CheckForDataOnSource()` unconditionally so that you are always checking for more bytes even if you already have some.

2) use `TIdIOHandler.ReadChar()` instead and get rid of the calls to `InputBufferIsEmpty()` and `CheckForDataOnSource()` altogether.  The downside is that you will lose data if a UTF-8 sequence decodes into a UTF-16 surrogate pair.  `ReadChar()` can decode surrogates, but it cannot return the second character in the pair (I have started working on new `ReadChar()` overloads for a future release of Indy that return `String` instead of `Char` so full surrogate pairs can be returned).

Comment: Does a Telnet server return multibyte character data?

Comment: It can, if that is what it wants to send, especially if Multibyte/Unicode enabled RFCs like 5198 and 2066 are implemented.  Also keep in mind that some protocols, like FTP, are based on Telnet, but have their own sementics for text encodings outside of Telnet, so it is possible for Telnet data to contain multibyte encoded text even if the Telnet protocol itself is not set to use text encodings.

Comment: thanks Remy, can you give me an example for each of two ways?

Comment: "for each of two ways", what do you mean?

Comment: InputBuffer and TIdIOHandler.ReadChar() way

Answer (score 2):

While your code is correct, the problem is most likely that the inputBuffer contains data that might contain null characters (#0) which would end the string.

Try  [Remy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1522658/800214) solution, and check what you get in the rawbytestring.

**Edit**

I didn't read that the OP was reading from a TelnetServer.
OP should use TidTelnet instead of IdTCPClient.

**Edit2**

I just read  [an older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989133/how-i-can-waiting-for-a-string-from-server-with-idtcpclient) of OP which explains the reason why he is not using TidTelnet.

/Daddy

Comment: I explained to him in that older post how to use TIdTelnet and still accomplish is goal.

Answer (score 1):

Telnet servers send a null character (#0) after each carriage return. This is most likely what you are seeing.

A null character encoded to UTF8 is still a single byte with the value of 0. Check to see if that's what you are receiving.